# Teracopy 3.1 flashes terminal window after finishing file transfers

Tags: windows, terminal, teracopy

I am using Teracopy 3.1 on a pc running Windows 10 x64.
After finishing any file transfers, Teracopy flashes a terminal window. How do I make it stop doing this?